# Design a algorithm: input is m inequalities of form xi ≠ xj, assign 0 or 1 to x such that number of inequalities are satisfied at least m/2

Tags: algorithm

Design ah algorithm: input is a stream of m inequalities of form xi ≠ xj for 1 ≤ i< j ≤ n. The algorithm will assign value 0 or 1 to each input , so the number of inequalities are satisfied at least m/2.(in expectation)

For example, if the input is (x1 ≠ x2), (x2 ≠ x3),(x1 ≠ x3), then assign x1=x2=1, x3=0 satisfies the condition.

How to write an algorithm that use O(log^O(1)(m+n)) space, assume m and n is known initially.

Output: the value of x1,...,xn and the number of satisfied inequalities

Answer (score 0):

Gosh, that isn't very much space, is it?

If we could remember all of the assignments, we could meet the spec by choosing each assignment uniformly at random and counting the stream as it comes. We can't though, so the go-to workaround is a hash function. Pairwise independence will suffice.

Assuming that the word size is w ≥ lg n, pick a random seed s and let h(i) = parity(i BITWISE-AND s). This is pairwise independent by standard linear algebraic arguments over GF(2).

Comment: Could you explain more